# How to ComplexExpand Jacobi elliptic functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, complex

It seems that *Mathematica* cannot expand Jacobi $\text{sn}, \text{cn}, \text{dn}$ functions. For example, A&S 16.20.1-3 say that for real $y$
$$
\operatorname{sn}(i y \mid m) = i\operatorname{sc}(y \mid 1-m),\\
\operatorname{cn}(i y \mid m) = \operatorname{nc}(y \mid 1-m),\\
\operatorname{dn}(i y \mid m) = \operatorname{dc}(y \mid 1-m),
$$
but `ComplexExpand[Re[JacobiSN[x, 1/2]]]` gives just `Re[JacobiSN[x, 1/2]]`. How do I teach *Mathematica* to properly expand those expressions?

Comment: You can teach *Mathematica* to expand those functions by writing your own function expander:  `myComplexExpand[expr_] := (expr /. {Re[JacobiSN[x_,1/2]] :> (*insert A&S expression here*), (*etc...*)})`.

Comment: `ComplexExpand[]` is really only usable for elementary functions, so you do need to write custom rules if you're going to be dealing with elliptic functions.